# WebView Login via POST

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse, webview

I am currently writing an app, which contains a login-screen and a 
webview. So far I managed to save the login data from the user 
via `SharedPreferences`, so that the user doesn't have to input
the data over and over again.

I also want the app to automatically log into the Website, which is
shown in the WebView, after the user clicked the login button.

The website I am showing in the WebView handles login requests via
HTTP-POST. This is a simplified version of the website:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<form action="/Login" method="post">    
<div class="dialog">
    <div>
        <div>Benutzername:</div>
        <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Passwort:</div>
        <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
</div>
```

Now I am trying to send a POST-Request via:

```
String url = "https://www.********.com/Login";                  
String postData = "UserName="+uname+"& Password="+pw;           
webview1.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

Somehow the login fails, but the username is shown in the login-formular.

Has anybody an idea what went wrong? Maybe the password encoding?

**€dit:**
If I replace `String postData = "UserName="+uname+"& Password="+pw;` with `String postData = URLEncoder.encode("UserName="+uname+"& Password="+pw);`, the username is not shown in the login-formular.

PS: My eclipse version can't find `EncodingUtils`. That's why I am using `URLEncoder`.

Comment: I see that quotes are missing after `/Login` in your form Tag. Are they also missing in your local code?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I'll correct it ;)